# Prove using laws and axiom of logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I have been looking at this question all day and have made a few attempts but can't seem to get any further.

Can someone please help with me proving this algebra equation and what laws I would need to use?

Forgive me for not knowing how to use the proper symbols on this. first time here, Didn't even know there was a forum for this.

I have also looked through already answered questions, and could not find anything similar.

This is the equation I need to prove

> $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \land q)$

So far I have

> $ p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \to q) \land (q \to p) $       The Equivalence Law
>
> $(p \to q) \land (q \to p) \equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p)  $  Implication Law
>
> $(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) $    not sure what law(I used a truth table)

I am not sure if I am even on the right track but if I am, when does it become proved? I think I may need like 3 or 4 more laws to be used.

Comment: axiom-of-choice ???????

Comment: the questions states to Use the laws and axioms of logic. when I was typing a tag, that is what came up...

Comment: What little squares? I don't see any squares?

Comment: Not quite sure what you need, but if one of your "laws" was derived by truth table, why don't you just check what you are trying to prove by a truth table?

Comment: all I see is " p RIGHTARROW q = (p OR q) RIGHTARROW (p AND q)

Comment: Because the question at uni needs to be answered using logic laws...

Comment: Using LaTeX (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would avoid these problems.

Comment: I will just edit the question with appropriate symbols. thank you

Comment: what the hell. I used that LaTeX. ?

Comment: If the LHS is LEFTRIGHTARROW, then you have to rewrite it as follows : $(p \to q) \land (q \to p) \equiv (p \lor q) \to (p \land q)$ that can be rewritten (by Material Implication and De Morgn) as : $(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) \equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)$.

Comment: The last step to prove the equivalence needs [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Truth_functional_connectives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last equivalence, while true, is not in the 'standard' list of equivalences. Below is how you prove it using 'standard' equivalences:

$$p \leftrightarrow q \equiv \text{ Equivalence}$$

$$(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p) \text{ Implication}$$

$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor p) \text{ Distribution}$$

$$((\neg p \lor q) \land \neg q)) \lor ((\neg p \lor q) \land p) \text{ Distribution x 2}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land p) \lor (q \land p) \text{ Complement x 2}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor \bot \lor \bot \lor (q \land p) \text{ Identity x 2}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q)\lor (q \land p) \text{ DeMorgan}$$

$$\neg (p \lor q) \lor (q \land p) \text{ Implication}$$

$$(p \lor q) \rightarrow (q \land p)$$

So here I used the following Equivalences in addition to Equivalence and Implication:

**Distribution**

$p \land (q \lor r) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$

**Complement**

$p \land \neg p \equiv \bot$

**Identity**

$p \lor \bot \equiv p$

**DeMorgan**

$\neg(p \lor q) \equiv \neg p \land \neg q$

Comment: Such an excellent answer. Thank you. I had no idea how to do the distributive law part with the given variables.

Comment: @Noob You're welcome! :)